# How can the commutator of two observables be realized in an experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, observables, quantum-measurements

Let's say we have two observables $A$ and $B$, and that we have an experimental setup in which we are able to measure both observables (not necessarily simultaneously). My question consists of two related questions:

- What is the meaning of the observable $BA$ in such an experiment? Is it simply measuring $A$ first, $B$ immediately afterwards, and then multiplying the two measurements?
- What is the meaning of $[A,B]$ in the experiment? If $AB$ and $BA$ are indeed obtained by measuring the observables in different orders, how could we possibly measure their linear combination, given that we can't revert the state after measuring either $AB$ or $BA$?

Examples of experiments would be appreciated. Especially for the case where $A$ and $B$ are momentum and displacement, though other observables are also fine, as long as they don't commute.

Comment: The commutator is in general not an observable if $A$ and $B$ are observables (hermitian), because it is not hermitian, except in the trivial case where both observabels commute and the commutator is zero.

Comment: And to add: $AB$ as well as $BA$ are not observables unless $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: @TobiasFunke I think the question should that have been asked is how to observe $\hat C=\mathfrak j [\hat A,\hat B]$, which is Hermitean, for an arbitrary pair of observables not just $\hat x ,\hat p$, see below answer of Hyperon.

Comment: @TobiasFunke your comment is fair but despite its ambiguity the question is not quite about a random operator. For argument's sake, let us just assume that we knew how to measure $\hat A$ or $\hat B$ and also knew that the issue of "measuring" $\hat C$ would be quite central to the various controversies in QM, then maybe help Vercassivelauonos to rephrase to something unambiguous and not just dismiss it so easily.

Comment: I've deleted my comment. Anyway, can you give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The product $AB$ of two hermitian operators $A$ and $B$ does, in general, not correspond to an observable, unless $[A,B]=0$. However, the operators $C=i[A,B]$ and $D=AB+BA$ are hermitian, thus corresponding (in principle) to observable quantities. Examples: $A=X$ and $B=P$ with $i[X,P]=-\hbar \mathbf{1}$ and $XP+PX$ (related to dilatations) or  $A= \sigma_x , \, B= \sigma_y$ with $i[\sigma_x, \sigma_y]=-2 \sigma_z$ and $\{\sigma_x, \sigma_y\}=0$.

Edit: In view of the comments above, a few more remarks on  subsequent measurements of two observables $A$ and $B$. Suppose a measurement of $A$ is performed on  a state described by the density operator $\rho$ with outcome $a \in \sigma(A)$, where $\sigma(A)$ denotes the spectrum of $A$. As a result of the measurement, we find the system in a new state described by the density operator $\rho_a = P_a \rho P_a/{\rm Tr}(P_a \rho P_a)$, where $P_a$ is the projection operator on the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $a$ of $A$. Performing now a measurement of the observable $B$  with outcome $b \in \sigma(B)$ changes the state $\rho_a$ into a new state $\rho_{ab}= Q_b \rho_a Q_b/{\rm Tr}(Q_b \rho_a Q_b)= Q_b P_a \rho P_a Q_b/{\rm Tr}(Q_b P_a \rho P_a Q_b)$, where $Q_b$ denotes the projection operator on the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $b$ of $B$.

Although the product $BA$ cannot be interpreted as an operator describing the subsequent measurement of the observables $A$ and $B$, the product $Q_b P_a$ of the two projection operators (in general not an observable either) plays this role in the sense described above: Starting with a state $\rho$, the measurement of $A$ with outcome $a$ followed by a measurement of $B$ with outcome $b$ results in a state $\rho_{ab}=\mathcal{N}_{ab} \, Q_b P_a \rho P_a Q_b$ with a normalization factor  $\mathcal{N}_{ab}= 1/{\rm Tr}(Q_b P_a \rho P_a Q_b)$.

Starting from the same state $\rho$, but inverting the order of the measurements ($B$ followed by $A$) leads to the state $\rho_{ba}= \mathcal{N}_{ba} P_a Q_b \rho Q_b P_a$. In general $\rho_{ab} \ne \rho_{ba}$, unless $P_a$ and $Q_b$ commute.

Answer (score 6):

> Let's say we have two observables $A$ and $B$, and that we have an experimental setup in which we are able to measure both observables (not necessarily simultaneously). My question consists of two related questions:

> - What is the meaning of the **observable** $BA$ in such an experiment?

(Emphasis added.)

$BA$ is *not* generally an "observable." The fact that $B$ and $A$ are observables, per the statement of your question, indicates that $BA$ is not an observable (unless $A$ and $B$ commute).

If $C=BA$ then $C^\dagger = AB$ because $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian. So $C^\dagger \neq C$ unless $A$ and $B$ commute, which you wrote you don't want to assume.

> Is it simply measuring $A$ first, $B$ immediately afterwards, and then multiplying the two measurements?

No.

> - What is the meaning of $[A,B]$ in the experiment? If $AB$ and $BA$ are indeed obtained by measuring the observables in different orders...

But $AB$ and $BA$ aren't "indeed obtained by measuring the observables in different orders..." So, the rest of the question is moot.

---

Here's one example.

As others have mentioned, the commutator is not directly observable. But, $i$ times the commutator certainly can be.

For example, Angular momenta obey the rule
$$
\vec L\times \vec L = i\vec L\;,
$$
so we see that $i$ times the commutator is just another component of the angular momentum.